# How to connect to Firebird using LibreOffice

Tags: java, jdbc, firebird, libreoffice

I have to create some reports using LibreOffice. I need to connecto a Firebird database using JDBC. I installed the driver (adding it to the classpath) and configured my connection to use

```
firebirdsql://server:alias
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
```

when I test the class I get this error:

```
"could not load driver class org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"
javax/resource/ResourceException
```

I tried in another machine and got the same message. Is there anything extra that should be added to classpath? What I´m missing here? I have both JRE and JDK installed and I´m using the first located in C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre7. There is no classpath environment variable defined nor global or for the user

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Thanks. There is no code when configuring the database connection (kind of a ODBC configuration). The code comes once the connection is achieved. I followed these [instructions](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/JDBC_Connection). The error appears when testing the driver class. I´m sure the class driver name is correct as shown [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/Jaybird_2_1_JDBC_driver_manual.pdf)

Comment: Did you remember to add `lib/connector-api-1.5.jar` to your LibreOffice classpath (in addition to adding `jaybird-2.2.5.jar`)? Also, did you notice that the datasource URL format for OpenOffice/LibreOffice Base is `jdbc:firebirdsql:oo://host[:port]/<database>` (note the additional `:oo`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jaybird has a required dependency on JCA (Java Connector Architecture), specifically JCA 1.5 (although newer should work as well), as documented in the [Jaybird 2.2.5 releasenotes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.5/release_notes.html#__RefHeading__8761_1080388197),

This means you need to include either `connector-api-1.5.jar` (from the `lib` folder) on the classpath, or you need to use `jaybird-full-2.2.5.jar` as that includes the classes from `connector-api-1.5.jar`.

Also your url is incorrect on two things: The format of the url is

```
jdbc:firebirdsql[:<subprotocol>]://<host>[:<port>]/<path-or-alias>
```

Which mean that `:alias` is wrong (it should be `/alias`). And as also remarked by Gord Thompson in the comments, you need to use the subprotocol `oo`, so you need to use protocol prefix `jdbc:firebirdsql:oo` to address difference in interpretation on JDBC, as also documented [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.5/release_notes.html#__RefHeading__3761_663895651). So your url should probably look like:

```
jdbc:firebirdsql:oo://server/alias
```

Comment: Thank you both. Worked smoothly. I could not elaborate on the connection string since the connection could not even made. The jdbc: was not included since LibreOffice inserts it and does not even let it be modified. I also tried without the "oo" subprotocol and also ran fine

Comment: @alvaroc without `:oo` will seem to work, but there are some edgecases you may run into regarding closed result sets and - depending on the config - some tables may appear readonly even if you have sufficient rights, see the second link.

Answer (score 3):

The above continues to be correct for Jaybird 4.0. Here are instructions in a little more detail, based on Debian 10. This is for an existing Firebird database that you can access already (i.e. can connect to and have an established username and perhaps pw).

Start LibreOffice but not Base - use Calc or just the general LibreOffice icon. Go to Tools, Options, LibreOffice and click on Advanced (in the top section, not in the Base options). Check the version number of the installed JRE. Leave the Advanced window open.

Download the corresponding version of the Jaybird zip file and unpack it. As pointed out by Mark Rotteveel in the original answer, jaybird has a dependency which may mean the bare jar file won't work. The simplest way around that is to use the "full" jar file:

```
jaybird-full-4.0.0.java11.jar
```

You may wish to move it into /usr/share/java for consistency but will probably need root permissions to do so.

Back in LibreOffice, click on the Class Path button in the Advanced window, then on Add Archive and add the .jar file. Close the Advanced window and restart LibreOffice.

Connecting: start LO Base. The Database Connect Wizard will appear. Select 
"Connect to an existing database". Specify JDBC as the driver and click Next.

Base supplies the jdbc: portion of the connect string, so add

```
firebirdsql:oo://host[:port]//<path to database file>
```

So, for example:

```
firebirdsql:oo://localhost:3050//home/dave/Firebird/employee.fdb
```

Note two occurances of "//" when using a full path.

When using an alias, there's only one set:

```
firebirdsql:oo://localhost:3050/employee
```

The JDBC driver class is:

```
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
```

Click Test Class to confirm that it is working. If not, retrace the steps above. The class test is independent of the connection string so no need to fill in both as you troubleshoot.

From that point on it should be self-evident. You'll end up with a .odb file that you can use to create Views, Reports, etc. on the industrial-strength Firebird back end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @davehill. Concise and clear.